# Yarn start script empty after installation

Tags: node.js, react-native, yarnpkg

I am new to React-Native and I wanted to install `yarn`
the command below is the error i received after initiaing `yarn start`
i also included the version of the `npm` and `nodejs` that i installed

```
PS E:\Native\confusion> node -v    
v12.18.1
PS E:\Native\confusion> npm -v
6.14.5
PS E:\Native\confusion> yarn -v     
1.22.4
PS E:\Native\confusion> yarn start                                                               
yarn run v1.22.4
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

And right here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that inside your `package.json` there is nothing defined for a `start` command. In order to fix it, you have to create a new json-node like this and fill it with whatever command you want the start script to execute:

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "COMMAND WHICH SHOULD GET EXECUTED GOES HERE"
  }
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "2.0.1"
  }
}
```

After you've defined this, you can execute `yarn start` and it will run your command.

Comment: yes but what should i write in it  I mean last time when i was working with ReactJS i didnt have to write the start script it was there , but now in React-native it didnt show any script for the start....can you tell me what to write or what should i write thank you

Comment: As I don't know what exactly you have installed or setup in your environment, I would say the best way to setup your project is to work with the documentation of react-native. They do have a whole part about setting up your environment for a react-native project and will guide you trough the process of initializing a project.